# error: expected ')' before '[' token

Tags: c, methods

I'm getting an error : expected ')' before '[' token

The line it is referring to is   `void quicksort(values[noOfNums],0,(noOfNums - 1));`

But i cannot see what is wrong with it.

Comment: We need way more code to tell what's wrong.

Comment: The word `void` makes this look like a declaration of quicksort, but you are apparently calling it.  Remove `void`.

Comment: The line make no sense to such an extreme degree, that there's absolutely no way to say what's wrong with it without more context. Is it a declaration? Is is a function call?

Answer (score 2):

The word "void" makes this look like a declaration of quicksort, but you are apparently calling it. Remove void, or write:

```
(void) quicksort( values[noOfNums], 0, noOfNums - 1 );
```

And for the sanity of future maintainers, please consider renaming `noOfNums` to something more understandable.